# contenteditable not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I have an element in my page that is meant to become editable once its parent is double clicked. so something like :

```
<div id="parent"><p class="editable"> enter text here </p></div>
```

and when the `#parent` is `dblclicked` I change the attribute `contenteditable` to true.

now the problem is that there are two things that prevent the user from editing the text once contenteditable is on:
1) the parent has lots of events and other stuff(including draggable and resizable) binded to it. If I do an `unbind()` to it, this part gets solved ( but I don't wanna do that ! )
2) I also use this code to disable text selection in my page :

```
function disableSelection(target){
    if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //IE route
        target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //Firefox route
        target.style.MozUserSelect="none"
    else //All other route (ie: Opera)
        target.onmousedown=function(){return false}
    target.style.cursor = "default"
}
```

and I've tried to exclude editable elements using :

```
disableSelection($(":not(.editable)").get(0));
```

but it seems to disable everything in the page. When I get rid of it, it solves the other half of the problem. 
so pretty much if I want to enable editing, I have to unbind all the events from the parent, and also get rid of disableSelection, which is not possible for me.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this ? the solution must be easier than what I think, but I think I'm just confusing myself right now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI .draggable() and .resizable() have a cancel property for which contained elements should not trigger the dragging

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-cancel

Is it just those two you need to ignore?

Comment: thanks, but if you see my question, draggable/resizable is just a small part of the problem. I have other click and dblclick events attached to the parent, and that's why I need to use unbind() to unbind anything attached to it ! plus, I still have the problem with disableselection

Comment: actually I just checked and disabling draggable/resizable for .editable using cancel property solves that part. but what should I do for the disableselection part ? how can I make sure that .editable elements aren't included in the function ?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle please? I'm not quite sure I understand the most recent bit of your question. thanks!

Comment: @jeovallender dont worry, I figured I have to compensate and get rid of some functions, so your answer was sufficient ! thanks